# How can we block X-Fordward-For header IP (https request) with IPtables

Tags: nginx, firewall, iptables, rate-limiting, fail2ban

Basic Overview 
We are trying to set up `Rate Limiting` on our server. we are using `Nginx` as a webserver and `fail2ban` for blocking IPs with `Iptables`.
IPtables can block IPs if a request hits direct our Nginx server(in this case `$remote_addr` is client IP).

But if it comes via some proxy server then proxy server passes client IP in `X-Fordwarded-For` header and Iptables unable to detect that(in this case `$remote_addr` is proxy server IP).

Is their some other ways we can block `X-Fordwarded-For` header IP? 
any help will be appreciable

IPtable IP block commmand - `iptables -A INPUT -s 111.112.212.112 -j DROP`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that using `iptables` (especially if the packets are encrypted due to https traffic).

But if you use fail2ban and nginx, you can try the action [nginx-block-map](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/action.d/nginx-block-map.conf). Just use variable [$http_x_forwarded_for](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) in the map (see action description) and provide it in log, fail2ban will monitor, so the filter would be able to capture it as an ID to ban.